# Is the phrase, "called police on..."proper usage?

Tags: word-usage

I saw the phrase: "[called police on...](https://www.gq.com/story/man-cops-black-family-pool)" (a black couple, etc) [frequently in newspapers](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&ei=YoxDW83vDcW56ATNxLn4DQ&q=called%20police%20on%20&oq=called%20police%20on%20&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3..41l2j0i19l4.1854.3296..3771...0....132.1296.4j8......0....1.........33i22i29i30.2nq9VGUjHk0). Is this proper usage?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. If you see the phrase used frequently in newspapers, most of which have established standards for grammar and usage, what rule or practice do you think it would violate? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @choster - I think that this construction can be  easily confused with the phrasal verb “call someone on” which has a different connotation as explained in  the answer below. Fr9m which, probably and understandably, the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is arguable whether that specific phrasing is proper, but it is certainly common, and acceptable. For example:

> "I called the police on my neighbor."

The proper phrasing would be much lengthier, such as:

> "I called the police to ask them to intervene in a situation involving
>   my neighbor."

EDIT:

A comment brought up a very similar phrasing which may confuse some:

*To call someone on some **thing***

For example:

> "I called the police on their loose relationship with the truth."

This is a colloquial terminology that means to confront someone regarding something. In this case, to confront the police regarding their dishonesty. It is not related to *called some **entity** on some **other entity***.

Comment: I think it is unidiomatic, it just means *call someone* on  something (for something that may have happened )

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I think so, if you were to say "I *called the police on* Bob" that would be correct.

Comment: _Why_ do you think it's correct? We're looking for answers that provide explanations, not just yes/no votes in an opinion poll. Also, the question says "called police on" but you say "called _the_ police on": are you claiming that "the" is needed for the sentence to be correct? (And, again, why?)